# 2-Form on $\mathbb{R}^3$ That Restricts to Surface Area 2-Form on Torus?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-topology, differential-forms, multiple-integral

I would like to find a 2-form on $\mathbb{R}^3$ that 1) restricts to the torus to give a generator of the top-dimensional de Rham cohomology of the torus and 2) restricts to the torus to give the surface area of the torus when integrated over it, for the sake of specificity, a torus with larger radius 3 in the $x-y$-plane and smaller radius 1, $T^2(3,1)$.

Per this webpage, https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Torus.html, a parameterization for $T^2(3,1)$ is given by

$\phi :\begin{cases} x = [3+\cos(v)]\cos(u) \\ y = [3+\cos(v)]\sin(u) \\ z = \sin(v) \end{cases}$,

$u \in [0,2\pi], v \in [0,2\pi]$

Per my musings on this webpage, http://airvigilante194.sdf.org/mathjax/orientedBordism.html, I came up with 1-forms, [**EDIT**: I think there should be a factor of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{3}$ on each variable in $\omega_1$, so it is the generator of $H^1_{dR}(S^1)$ on the circle of radius 3 which returns the "length" when integrated over that circle]

$\displaystyle \omega_1 = \frac{-\frac{1}{3}y}{\left(\frac{1}{3}x\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{3}y\right)^2}\ dx + \frac{\frac{1}{3}x}{\left(\frac{1}{3}x\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{3}y\right)^2}\ dy = \frac{-3y}{x^2+y^2}\ dx + \frac{3x}{x^2+y^2}\ dy$ and

$\displaystyle \omega_2 =  \left[\frac{-z}{z^2 + \left(\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right)(y-3)^2 + \left(\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\right)(x-3)^2}\right]\ \left[\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)dy + \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)dx\right] + \left[\frac{\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)(y-3)+ \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)(x-3)}{z^2 + \left(\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right)(y-3)^2 + \left(\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\right)(x-3)^2}\right]\ dz$,

(taking linear combinations of the $(x-3)$- and $(y-3)$-variables in $\omega_2$)

and a 2-form $\eta = \omega_1 \wedge \omega_2$.

I **think** $\eta$ should be a 2-form on $\mathbb{R}^3$ that restricts to give a 2-form on $T^2(3,1)$ whose integral over $T^2(3,1)$ is its surface area, but I'm very unsure about $\omega_2$.

**EDIT**: Again per https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Torus.html, in the parameterization $\phi$ of the torus, this should be the pull-back of the plain-vanilla surface area form on the torus $\theta = \iota^*(dx \wedge dy \wedge dz)$ (the pull-back of the plain-vanilla volume form $dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ via the inclusion map $\iota: T^2(3,1) \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$) to the parameter space

$\phi^*(\theta) = [3+\cos(v)]\ (du \wedge dv)$

and if I integrate the constant function 1 over the torus in the parameterization $\phi$, I should get for the surface area

$\displaystyle \iint\limits_{T^2(3,1)} 1\ dS = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} [3+\cos(v)]\ du\ dv = 12\pi^2$

I made up a wxMaxima script to try to compute the integral of $\eta$ via a pull-back along $\phi$, http://airvigilante194.sdf.org/mathjax/Form%20Integrals%2001.wxmx, but it keeps crashing, likely because I'm doing something very wrong with $\omega_2$.

I know I should be able to puzzle this out myself, but could someone help me come up with the correct explicit formula for $\omega_2$? I would be very grateful.

Comment: (I think I neglected to mention that, in addition to $\eta$ integrating to the surface area of $T^2$, $\eta$ restricted to $T^2$ should generate $H^2_{dR}(T^2$.)

Comment: I have a picture in my head which I will try to convey. It is that of a $1$-parameter family of non-intersecting tori, which starts out from the degenerate "torus" the z-axis at say $w = 0$, is a torus containing $T^2(3,1)$ "inside it" for $0 < w < 1$, is the torus $T^2(3,1)$ at $w = 1$, becomes a torus contained "inside" $T^2(3,1)$ for $w > 1$ and then degenerates to the circle of radius $3$ as $w \mapsto \infty$.

Comment: Then the vector field $N$ obtained by partially differentiating $x$, $y$ and $z$ with respect to $w$ is a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^3$, which I think vanishes on the $z$-axis and on the circle of radius $3$ in the $xy$-plane, and is equal to the inward unit normal when restricted to $T^2(3,1)$ (well, if it is not of unit norm, one could simply scale it appropriately). Then just take the inner product of $N$ with the volume form in $\mathbb{R}^3$. This may be similar to what you are doing with formulas, but I feel that the picture helps.

Comment: A similar picture is kind of used in twistor theory by the way. See for instance fig. 2, related to Robinson congruence of twisting light rays in [Twistor theory at 50](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rspa.2017.0530).

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it!

Comment: For the torus in $\mathbb{R}^4$, one would just use $\displaystyle \omega_1 = \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\ dx + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\ dy$ and $\displaystyle \omega_1 = \frac{-w}{z^2+w^2}\ dz + \frac{z}{z^2+w^2}\ dw$, and $\eta = \omega_1 \wedge \omega_2$. This is what I'm trying to reproduce with my $\omega_2$.

Comment: I see. There may be a map from $\mathbb{R}^4$ onto $\mathbb{R}^3$ which is a submersion from the flat torus onto $T^2(3,1)$ (some kind of moment map associated to a triholomorphic isometric action of either $\mathbb{R}$ or $U(1)$). Maybe working out this map will help you?

Comment: Thanks again! I appreciate it!